# UdpSink in GStreamer is not working in Windows

Tags: windows, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtp

I am new to GSTreamer.
I tried to upsink a video using GStreamer. While running the folloing command,

> gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! udpsink port=5200

I get warnings as follows.

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0: Attempting to send a UDP packets larger than maximum size (115200 > 65507)
Additional debug info:
gstmultiudpsink.c(715): gst_multiudpsink_send_messages (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0:
Reason: Error sending message: A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself.
0:00:56.934530706  4912 0000000002F09640 WARN            multiudpsink gstmultiudpsink.c:715:gst_multiudpsink_send_messages:<udpsink0> warning: Attempting to send a UDP packets larger than maximum size (115200 > 65507)
0:00:56.939093412  4912 0000000002F09640 WARN            multiudpsink gstmultiudpsink.c:715:gst_multiudpsink_send_messages:<udpsink0> warning: Reason: Error sending message: A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself.
```

What is the problem in GStreamer parameters?

Is there anything missing in that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need payloading before before transmitting a video on UDP.

```
 gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! rtpraw4vpay ! udpsink port=5200
```

But transmitting raw video over udp is not preferred. A better way to transmit video is to encode it to reduce the size. I'd prefer h264 encoding for optimum size.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! x264enc ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=5200
```

You will receive this stream with

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5200 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using Windows 7 machine. rtpraw4vpay or x264enc are not available in my machine.

Comment: In Linux, it is easy to download. Is there any similar way to download the plugins in Windows?

Comment: x264enc and most of the video encoders are in gst-libav package. I don't know if there's precompiled packages, you might need to build it yourself and add the location of dlls to `%GST_PLUGIN_PATH%`.

Comment: I am trying your two last commands but nothing is happening. No error, just "New clock: GstSystemClock" on both side.